# MFC Message Queue Limit

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

My understanding of the size limit on the message queue in a MFC thread comes from the explanation on PostThreadMessage page of MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As stated, the limit by default is 10000 messages. I am trying to understand exactly what this limit is. I see it being one of two thing.

**Scenario A**

I have a GUI that is handling messages. The rate at which the messages are being placed in the queue is greater than that at which these messages are being pulled off the queue and handled. In this case messages accumulate, eventually there are 10000 messages on the queue, another message tries to join the queue, but it then fails.

**Scenario B**

I have a GUI that is handling messages. The rate at which message are being placed in the queue is less that then rate at which these messages are being pulled of the queue and handled. Messages do no accumulate on the queue. But after my queue has seen 10000 messages, it is rendered useless, so effectively, my message queue has a limited operational life.

The more I think about it, the answer should be Scenario A... but stranger things have happened..

Comment: This question is confusing to me. It is unclear what kind of messages do you mean - MFC is mainly a GUI library, i.e. mainly GUI messages are sent. MFC isn't aimed at messages sent among threads. See PostMessage() function.

Comment: What?! How does your comment even relate to my question? For starters, what is to say that my question is not referring to a GUI based application? Maybe the question is confusing, but so is your comment.

Comment: Actually, your Scenario B is a bit confusing... From the linked article: `GetLastError returns ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA when the message limit is hit.` So, every attempt to send/post message when the queue is full fails, that's all.

Comment: (@AlKepp)PostThreadMessage is used in the event when you have a message queue in a CWinThread. Why am I using a message map in a CWinThread? Because it suits my application. I wish my thread to do some work, in the mean time some other threads may wish to send it updates, I don't want these updates to interrupt the work I am doing, so I have these update placed in a queue to be serviced next time the thread has some free time... hence why I have a message queue. My question was not, "Should I use a messages in my CWinThread implementation.."

Comment: So maybe it isn't B, I'm leaning away from B.. mainly because it seems a little illogical in a programming sense..

Comment: BTW, running a long function in UI thread is not a good idea, simple worker threads should be used instead. UI thread (generally, every thread with a message loop) must be always responsive. Back to the article `If your application exceeds the limit, it should be redesigned to avoid consuming so many system resources.`

Comment: I guess I need to understand what the lifetime of a message is. So thread issues a PostMessage to another thread. This receiver thread is busy when the PostMessage occurs, so the message is placed in the queue, this message is also the only message in the queue. Eventually the receiver thread has time to check the message queue, it sees there is a message there, it deals with it. In the mean time there were no other messages placed on the queue. Does the operation of the queue mean that once the message has been handled, it no longer exist?

Comment: Yes, unless receiving thread uses PeekMessage with PM_NOREMOVE flag.

Comment: OK - let's ignore the fact that it is "not a good idea".. I like the idea of a message queue, as I stated in an earlier comment it allows me to update certain things, only when the thread is not busy doing anything..

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Thank you Alex Farber.. Post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as an answer :) add this link to your answer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: As requested. The "bad idea" part is not included in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked article: `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA` when the message limit is hit. So, every attempt to send/post message when the queue is full fails, that's all.

Generally, destination thread handles the messages and removes them from the queue. `PeekMessage` with `PM_NOREMOVE` flag allows to handle the message without removing it. For reference, `PeekMessage` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks again.. So why would a thread receive a message, but not remove it from the queue? Is it to reduce overhead? Or is it so you can search through the queue to find "higher" priority messages, deal with these and then work your way through the lower priority messages

Comment: This may be done for pre-processing, when PeekMessage just checks, whether some message presents, and leaves it for handling in another place. Finally, all messages are removed.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/26/9375457.aspx : This limit really shouldn't be hit under normal circumstances. It's intended to catch runaway processes.